# Google Fusion Table Query

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

The following javascript code is not working which has a query to google fusion table.

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(37.447038,-122.160575), 'zoom': 11, 'mapTypeId' :  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'callback': function(map) {

$('#map_canvas').gmap('loadFusion', { 'query': { 


    'from': '297050' ,
    'orderBy': ST_DISTANCE('Address', LATLNG(37.447038,-122.160575)),
    'limit':10 } });

var t = setTimeout(function() {$('#dialog').dialog('close');}, 2000);                       
                }
});
```

If I remove the query line having the orderby clause (as below) it works fine

```
$('#map_canvas').gmap({ 'center': new google.maps.LatLng(37.447038,-122.160575), 'zoom': 11, 'mapTypeId' :  google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'callback': function(map) {

$('#map_canvas').gmap('loadFusion', { 'query': { 


    'from': '297050' ,

    'limit':10 } });

var t = setTimeout(function() {$('#dialog').dialog('close');}, 2000);                       
                }
});
```

Please Advise hot to fix this query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "orderBy" property seems to work as a string.  Instead of:

```
'from': '297050' ,
'orderBy': ST_DISTANCE('Address', LATLNG(37.447038,-122.160575)),
'limit':10 } });
```

Try (notice the double quotes (") around the orderBy property:

```
      query: {
        select: 'Address',
        from: 297050,
        orderBy: "ST_DISTANCE('Address', LATLNG(37.447038,-122.160575))",
        limit:5
      },
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_orderByQuery.html)